# Some images not loading after changing IP on local wordpress install

Tags: images, configuration

Im running wordpress locally (via docker), and everything is working fine.
At some point, I changed some router configurations, and my IP changed, from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.2 (just an example, but you get it).

I updated the new IP in Wordpress Settings>General, Wordpress Address and Site Address.
I checked, and these changes have reflected in the database as well in wp_options, siteurl and home.

Most images on the site were showing fine, but a few were not loading.
Going into Wordpress again, Media, I saw a message saying if I wanted to run an update database process. Clicked yes, and after that, some more images started loading, but still not all.
In my media library, going into the images, shows that they are pointing to the new IP, 192.168.1.2, but the site is still not loading them.
And if, on the site, I right click the broken image link, and copy image address, it is still pointing to the old IP (192.168.1.1).

Is there any other update process I can run to correctly point the images to the new IP?
It's weird that the media library seems to be displaying them correctly, with the correct IP, but Chrome (and other browsers) are still trying to look on the old one.
Already tried incognito window and clearing caches.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I ended up deleting the images and re uploading them, because I couldn't find any other solution.
Tried this:
https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/#additional-items-of-note
But didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try running [the WP CLI command `search-replace`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) to update all uses in the database.

If you cannot access the WP CLI, there are plugins that will do database search and replaces as well.